# I just bought an HP 4t-1000 and cannot access the BIOS to change the boot order and install Ubuntu from a USB

Tags: boot, hp, bios

The <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, and <kbd>ESC</kbd> keys do not do anything. I called HP support (terrible), and when I press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key during startup, it brings me to a RAID reconfiguration screen and not the BIOS.

Specs:
14" HP 4t-1000 SleekBook
4GB RAM
500GB Hard Drive
32GB SSD

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to "flash BIOS" (update it) check this link: 
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00042629&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=5274535

Comment: I did that, and will try it again. It had no effect the first time. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, during boot process you can press <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> key (usually on the row with all the F1-12 keys) to *"freeze"* the screen. Also, when you hibernate your system, options to enter Boot-Setup do not appear. Do normal shutdown first (not hibernate), then *"freeze"* the screen when you turn on the computer and look carefully for "Enter BIOS setup" or anything similar. You can press repeatedly the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key to unfreeze and freeze the screen again.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do not have that key, only PRT SC and DELETE. There is the word PAUSE on the SHIFT key, but it does not do as you indicated.

Comment: hmm, there is a chance your BIOS could be locked anyway. You could try @Emanuel Ström answer below and link.

Comment: Thank you very much! I do, indeed, think the BIOS is locked.

Comment: OK, you did that. refer to your manual or simply trial and error with combination of the keys (Probably Fn key + Shift?). make sure you do normal shutdown in windows (select carefully from the menu)

Comment: it also says: "To access the Boot Device Options window, turn on the computer and immediately press the esc key to display the Startup Menu, and then press the F9 key."

Comment: Success! I tried the Emanuel Ström method below a second time, and I was able to access the BIOS. Thank you all for your help and patience! I'm happy to be part of such a great community.